# copy after grep in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep, command

Is there a way to copy the files captured by `grep` into a new directory?

I am using the following command to compare 2 directories

```
diff -q folder1 folder2 | grep 'string'
```

I want to move the files that contain this 'string' into a new directory.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man xargs.

```
ls *.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} ../{}
```

If I remember the syntax correctly

so assuming your diff+grep produces paths

```
diff -q folder1 folder2 | grep "Only in blaa" | cut -d " " -f 4- | xargs -I {} cp {} ../{}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, I'm not quite sure how to use this command in conjugation with grep (I have seen many examples online but still cannot understand it) what text file are you referring to in the loop of the above command?

Comment: i put the "ls" in `` because it will then be easier to replace it with any other shell stuff producing a list of paths.

Comment: error404 , just put your whole diff+grep inside those `` and see what happens. it should work if your diff+grep produces a list of paths like ls does

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen, seems like it is close to working but, I am getting the following error message "cp: cannot stat `Only in /folder1/ : file1 .jpeg': No such file or directory" ...

 obviously, this 'Only in /folder1/' is my string that grep looks up

Comment: well then you need to grep that "only" part out and make sure cp only sees the path part.

Comment: maybe use sed or cut to remove the "only" part.

Comment: or maybe use rsync to do this syncing of directories ;)

Comment: try that modified line with "cut"

Comment: ofcourse replace "blaa" with your proper grepping instruction

Comment: I feel terrible for seeking that much help, sorry mate. The Cut command is actually cutting the whole directory, because the string is "Only in /folder1/" and cut removes the /folder1/ here as well - duh! I don't even deserve the +1 on this question!

Comment: just tune the "cut" parameter up and down to produce the correct path , and if needed add directories as prefixes in the xargs cp - clause

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen, Today I have set the right path for the command, yet it tells me `cp: cannot stat /the/perfect/directory/V.jpeg': No such file or directory` for all files, any idea what's going on?

Comment: maybe the first / is too much or maybe there are some weird characters in the path that the shell is interpreting wrong. like spaces.

Answer (score 2):

using awk is possible :

```
ls | grep string | awk '{print "cp", $1, "newDirectory/"}' | sh
```

as Tripleee said should be

```
ls | awk '/string/ {print "cp", $1, "newDirectory/"}' | sh
```

edit : should work in exemple with `diff -q` command :

```
diff -q folder1 folder2 | awk '/string/ {gsub(":",""); print "cp", $3 "/" $4, "newFolder/"}' | sh
```

Comment: Also `grep | awk` is an antipattern; http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: thanks for correction. What about this way ? :
    diff -q folder1 folder2 | awk '/string/ {print "cp, $3 "/" $4, "newsDirectory/"}' | sed -e "s/://g" | sh

Comment: Gawk has `gsub` and even with regular Awk it seems avoidable to postprocess with `sed`.

Comment: thanks again for improvment `diff -q folder1 folder2 | awk '/string/ {gsub(":",""); print "cp", $3 "/" $4, "newFolder/"}' | sh`

Answer (score 0):

try this

set -- $(diff  $PWD/folder1 $PWD/folder2 | grep afile | tr ':' '/')

cp $3$4  newdir